# .htaccess URL rewrites to the wrong file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to change my urls from mywebsite.co/keyword to mywebsite.co/web/keyword i found a few ways to do this but it always causes problems with my other rewrites here is what i have so far only problem with it is it wont redirect mywebsite.co/keyword to mywebsite.co/web/keyword

```css
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^screenshot/ - [L]


# If requested resource exists as a file or directory, skip next two rules
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [S=2]

# when there is no space make an external redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^info/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /search/info/info.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^web/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /search/web/index.php?search=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /search/video/video.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^images/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /search/images/image.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /search/news/news.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /search/products/product.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^maps/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /search/maps/maps.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^space/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /search/space/space.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^web/ /search/web/index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^info/ /search/info/info.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^videos/ /search/video/video.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^images/ /search/images/image.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^news/ /search/news/news.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^products/ /search/products/product.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^maps/ /search/maps/maps.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^space/ /search/space/space.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Which php file should handle `mywebsite.co/web/keyword`?

Comment: /search/web/index.php?search=$1

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^screenshot/ - [L]

# If requested resource exists as a file or directory, skip next two rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^info/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /search/info/info.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^web/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /search/web/index.php?search=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /search/video/video.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^images/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /search/images/image.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /search/news/news.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /search/products/product.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^maps/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /search/maps/maps.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^space/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /search/space/space.php?keyword=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^web/?$ /search/web/index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^info/?$ /search/info/info.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^videos/?$ /search/video/video.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^images/?$ /search/images/image.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^news/?$ /search/news/news.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^products/?$ /search/products/product.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^maps/?$ /search/maps/maps.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^space/?$ /search/space/space.php [QSA,L]
```